# Days or workout-sessions as independent variable when doing a regression analysis on exercise

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm monitoring heartrate recovery after fitness workout and want to see if there is any improvement. I'm considering to either use days since I started excercising as my independent variable or use wokrout seission numbers with days since start as a variable.

The thinking is to look at all the workout-aspects like recovery-time between sessions etc or just see workouts as "treatments". What are the pros and cons of the different approaches?